# Select non-continuous cells based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with letter "D" and nothing else put in random cells. What code do I use to select/copy - or even better dim as range - all of those cells?

So far I Have the following:

```
Sub SelectD()

Dim AllD As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    If cell = "D" Then
        Set AllD = '???
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Thanks,
Bartek

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Union to add the cells to the range as they are found.

```
Sub SelectD()

Dim AllD As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    If cell = "D" Then
        If AllD Is Nothing then
            Set AllD = cell
        Else
            Set AllD = Union(cell,AllD)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

'Do something with AllD
Debug.Print AllD.Address
End Sub
```